# cd in binary directory

Tags: unix, command-line

I'm looking for a way to `cd`directly on the directory of a binary file.

Let me precise a bit.

```
$ which brew
/usr/local/bin/brew
```

I want to can directly jump to `/usr/local/bin`.

Obviously, below isn't working but I guess what I search is something like :

```
$ cd `which brew`
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `dirname` command:

```
cd $(dirname $(which brew))
```

Or

```
path=$(which brew) && cd ${path%/*}
```

Comment: In case `brew` doesn't exist in the path then `which` will fail and it'll simply do `cd` (takes to home dir). So prefer to the latter if that's an issue.